# Renumerating indexed JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I have data stored in a JSON - and one of the fields is an index that determines the order in which the other data is done. Imagine

```
 [
    {
    “Action” : “Wake up”,
    “id” : 1
    },
    {
    “Action” : “Make coffee”,
    “id” : 2
    },
    {
    “Action” : “Check Email”,
    “id” : 3
    }
   ]
```

Problem is that if I want to include an extra item mid-list - I am having to manually re-enter all the indices. E.g. if I decided I should insert

```
{
“Action” : “Feed Cat”,
“id” : 2
}
```

Then all the lower indices would be wrong.

Is there a tool that can automatically renumber so that the id fields were always sequential 1,2,3,4,5, however I moved around the data items?

There is an option to add a plugin script - sample is below - but I don't know JavaScript so I can't clearly see how to edit it to do the bulk edit I want

```
PJEPlugIn = {        
JSON processing function, will take two arguments                                                          @param json    JSON object from editor, maybe null for inform JSON      @param jsonStr JSON text from editor     
@return Return value can be any valid JavaScript object, string will be treated as JSON text      */     
func: function(json, jsonStr) {         
return eval('(' + jsonStr + ')');    
 } 
}
```

Comment: the question is not clear... what do you think, what will happed ? when you insert an item in mid-list.

Comment: ` [
    {
    “Action” : “Wake up”,
    “id” : 1
    },{
“Action” : “Feed Cat”,
“id” : 2
},
    {
    “Action” : “Make coffee”,
    “id” : 2
    },
    {
    “Action” : “Check Email”,
    “id” : 3
    }
   ]`

Comment: And then I have to manually update the items downstream to get it back into being sequential ids [ { “Action” : “Wake up”, “id” : 1 },{ “Action” : “Feed Cat”, “id” : 2 }, { “Action” : “Make coffee”, “id” : 3 }, { “Action” : “Check Email”, “id” : 4 } ]

Comment: I imagined there would be a widget in my JSON editor that would let me batch update a 'special' field (id) to follow the rule 'nth item has id = n'. But I can't find anything that will do it.

Comment: After insert a new item in mid-list, Update all item `id`, code: `items.forEach((item, i) => item.id = i + 1)` You don't need to use any `id` for that, simple use array index.

Comment: Where are you using those commands? I am using JSON as a standalone portable data format - it's not part of a larger project. I'm just using 'JSON Editor' programmes downloaded from Mac App store - which have been great for sanitising the data - but don't let me do bulk/smart edits to the data. I guess I should probably make my own mini project just to give me the control I want over the data formatting - but it feels elaborate for something that I thought would have been a super standard 'ask'.

Comment: Actually - I do have the ability to use a script within the JSON editor - but I don't Java, so I don't really know how to handle it. The sample provided is:

Comment: Use a programing language. Many programing language is created just for data manipulation, mathematics... So you have much more control and efficient manipulation. Also its so easy and fun. Bsc your data is JSON format, I suggest you to use JavaScript, You also need a VM (like Node or Deno)

Comment: `PJEPlugIn = {  
     JSON processing function, will take two arguments                                                    
     @param json    JSON object from editor, maybe null for inform JSON
     @param jsonStr JSON text from editor
     @return Return value can be any valid JavaScript object, string will be treated as JSON text
     */
    func: function(json, jsonStr) {
        return eval('(' + jsonStr + ')');
    }
}; `

Comment: Why do you even need an index? Isn't each item's position in the array inherently its index (0-based)?

Comment: Later downstream it was useful to have the 'number' of the loaded data item 'readable' ... but it is an option to fix up my downstream non-Java code to make that field redundant ...

Comment: In fact - I think that is where I will fix it. I'm uncomfortable in Javascript - so I will sanitise the data within my own code at the point of use ... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any programing language, With java script, use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
let data = [{
    "Action": "Wake up",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "Action": "Make coffee",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "Action": "Check Email",
    "id": 3
  }
];
let item = { "Action" : "Feed Cat", "id" : 2 }
// with Array.splice() method
// 1st argument is insertion index (start)
// 2nd delete count
// 3nd insertion item
data.splice(1, 1, item);

console.log(data)
```

**Note:** In computing, index count from 0.

Comment: Thank you. Could you possible draft me something similar - but that would work as a script without leaving my editor - and that bulk renumbers my records rather than handles the splice (so overwrites id from 1 .... N whatever they ended up being)